# Sencha Touch app components not visible until touching

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, android-webview

My Sencha Touch 2.4.0 app's Viewport config looks like this:

```
xtype: 'mainviewport',
config: {
    layout: 'card',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    listeners: {
        painted: function() {
            console.log('xxxxxx viewport painted');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adding another view into the Viewport using following controller code:

```
var vp = Ext.Viewport.down('mainviewport');
vp.add(view);
vp.setActiveItem(view);
```

The issue is, only on Android JellyBean (4.1 - 4.3), I don't see the `view` rendered on the screen. But, when I tap once, it get's rendered and its `painted` method is getting called. I also see that the `'xxxxxx viewport painted'` line is printed even before I tapped the screen.

I have tried a lot of options in the past week, including downgrading sencha touch to 2.3.0 but still no luck. Highly appreciate any support.

Comment: Not sure but try the following: 
var vp = Ext.Viewport.down('mainviewport');
view = vp.add(view);
vp.setActiveItem(view);

Also, it might be helpful to upgrade to 2.4.1 as it has many fixes.

Comment: I have tried your first suggestion. Also upgraded to 2.4.2 but both options didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [bug fixes for Chrome 43](https://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=90&a=58) which have been recently added to Touch 2.4.2. Since this is a problem affecting Android, I would imagine the Chromium updates could be to blame.

Comment: I have upgraded to ST 2.4.2 but still no luck

Comment: We're also experiencing the same issues.  After upgrading to Sencha Touch 2.4 to fix some issues on Lollipop, we noticed that our forms disappeared until you tap or swipe on KitKat.  They do, however, work in Lollipop.  Still trying to track down why as well...

Comment: @Technologyrocks please answer this question if you found one. We still don't have a solution.